# SmallRye Mutiny How to access, modify and append the final element in Multi<String>?

Tags: java, json, reactive-streams, mutiny, smallrye

Within my application, I am dynamically creating and returning customers in JSON format. I would like to differentiate each customer, so I am adding a comma after the creation of each customer, but I do not wish to add the comma separation to the last element, so I would like to remove it.

Hence, I need to access the last element and make the modification, but I am running into some problems when doing the same. I tried to do this but was unable to concatenate the same. I am unable to get the last customer without a comma. The following is the code I have:

```
  public static Multi <String> generate(final Input input) {
      final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

      try {
          final Multi < String > generatedCustomer = Multi.createFrom().publisher(CustomerGenerator.createModels(input)).onItem().transform(
              event - > {
                  try {
                      return objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(event) + ",";
                  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  return null;
              });

          final Multi < String > lastCustomer = generatedEvents.select().last().onItem().transform(i - > i.substring(0, i.length() - 1));

          return Multi.createBy().concatenating().streams(generatedCustomer, lastCustomer);

      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new CustomerException("Exception occurred during the generation of Customer : " + e);
      }
  }
```

How to achieve this?

**Updated**
My application currently produces customer information in the following format asynchronously, so I would like to add a wrapper to it and make it look like the following JSON.

```
{
 "name": "Batman",
 "age": 45,
 "city": "gotham"
}
```

I would like to add a wrapper to it and make it like this:

```
{
  "isA": "customerDocument",
  "createdOn": "2022-10-10T12:29:43",
  "customerBody": {
    "customerList": [
      {
        "name": "Batman",
        "age": 45,
        "city": "gotham"
      },
      {
        "name": "superman",
        "age": 50,
        "city": "moon"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hence, I have added a code something like this:

```
 public static Multi < String > generate(final Input input) {
     final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

     try {
         final Multi < String > beginDocument = Multi.createFrom().items("\"isA\":\"customerDocument\", \"creationDate\":\"" + Instant.now().toString() + "\", \"customerBody\":{ \"customerList\":[");
         final Multi < String > generatedCustomer = Multi.createFrom().publisher(CustomerGenerator.createModels(input)).onItem().transform(
             event - > {
                 try {
                     return objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(event) + ",";
                 } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 return null;
             });

         final Multi < String > lastCustomer = generatedEvents.select().last().onItem().transform(i - > i.substring(0, i.length() - 1));

         return Multi.createBy().concatenating().streams(beginDocument, generatedCustomer, lastCustomer, Multi.createFrom().items("]}}"));

     } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new CustomerException("Exception occurred during the generation of Customer : " + e);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You can append items to a multi using `.onCompletion().continueWith(...)`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you are asking. Unless  Mutiny as a way to say "all events except for the last one". But why do you need to add the comma? The JSON is emitted as soon as available, what's the purpose of the comma?

Comment: @DavideD'Alto The problem is that the application emits a single Customer object but I would like to add a wrapper to that JSON so I need to append them to a pre-existing array so I need to add `,` after each object so it adheres to JSON schema. I have added an example of Customer obect that's provided by application.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you've asked:

```java
 public static Multi <String> generate(final Input input) {
      final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

      try {
          final Multi<String> generatedCustomer = Multi.createFrom().publisher(CustomerGenerator.createModels(input)).onItem().transform(
              event - > {
                  try {
                      return objectMapper
                          .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                          .writeValueAsString(event);
                  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      return null;
                  }
              });


          Multi<String> customersMulti = generatedCustomer
              .skip().last().map( s -> s  + "," );
          Multi<String> lastMulti = generatedCustomer
              .select().last();

          return customersMulti.onCompletion().switchTo(lastMulti);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new CustomerException("Exception occurred during the generation of Customer : " + e);
      }
  }
```

You can find more [information in the documentation](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/1.7.0/guides/take-skip-items/#skipping-items)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and solution but the problem is that with `Multi<String>` we need to store it in the list again right? If there is a huge data set there could be a memory problem, right? This is something I would like to avoid because the application has to handle a very large data set. Is there something else I can try so we can avoid storing in list?

Comment: I thought so. But if you need to create a single JSON string, at some point you need to collect all this customers, wouldn't my second solution that returns a Uni work? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess you want to generate the array dynamically

Comment: Actually, I think I know how you can do it. Gimme a minute

Comment: Yes, I would like to generate dynamically. I am looking into `Uni` but the problem is that it will break the other depending projects as all of them are using the `Multi` and I am not allowed to change it. So looking for a solution using `Multi`

Comment: Please take your time :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the new solution but for some reason, this only returns me one customer and does not return the subsequent customers at all.

Comment: That's weird, I've created a quick test and it works for me. Maybe there is an exception? Anyway, selecting the first and skipping it is your best bet in my opinion. If you can create a test project somewhere that I can run, I will have a look. You can also try `return Multi.createBy().concatenating().streams( firstMulti, remainingMulti );`

Comment: I will check again. One quick question: in your code, you are skipping the first and adding comma (`,`) to all the remaining so doesn't that mean you will add `,` even for the last one? Because we would like to skip the adding of `,` to the last customer object actually.

Comment: Well, yes. I thought you wanted to generate an array.

Comment: I've just found out that you can actually skip the last item. Let me update the answer

Comment: Now it will update all the items except for the last one. I should have read the docs better

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But in my case the last element is getting skipped. I copied the exact code from your answer but still missing the last element. Have you also tried with multiple values? I am not getting the final Customer information in my response.

Comment: I don’t know. Maybe it’s the way CustomerGenerator.createModels is implemented?

Comment: Actually if I add just this then I am getting all customer information `return Multi.createBy().concatenating().streams(generatedCustomer);` but if I change it based on your answer `return customersMulti.onCompletion().switchTo(lastMulti);` then I am not getting the last customer information. So I believe it's not appending the last one due to a recent change and everything else works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249098/discussion-between-batman-2008-and-davide-dalto).

Comment: Maybe the customer publisher you are using, `.publisher(CustomerGenerator.createModels(input))`, because once you have generated the first stream (`customersMulti`), doesn't allow selecting the last. Hard to say with the info you gave us.

Comment: Yup, I can completely understand. I will try to create a sample project and provide you. But I am just confused because when I use ```return generatedCustomer;``` then everything works fine but when I split the ```generatedCustomer``` to ```customersMulti```and use it then the problem is arising so really confused.

Comment: You could create a fake generatedCustomer and see if it works. For example: `final Multi<String> generatedCustomer = Multi.createFrom().items("{\"name\": \"Batman\", \"age\": 45,\"city\": \"gotham\"}", ...);'`

Comment: Thanks a lot again for providing various ideas and workarounds. They were beneficial but this is something worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74237238/7584240

Comment: Well, whatever works.

Answer (score 0):

The following is something I tried and it worked:

```
 public static Multi < String > generate(final Input input) {
     final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

     try {
         final Multi < String > beginDocument = Multi.createFrom().items("\"isA\":\"customerDocument\", \"creationDate\":\"" + Instant.now().toString() + "\", \"customerBody\":{ \"customerList\":[");

         final AtomicBoolean firstEntry = new AtomicBoolean(true);

         final Multi < String > generatedCustomer = Multi.createFrom().publisher(CustomerGenerator.createModels(input)).onItem().transform(
             event - > {
                 try {
                     if (firstEntry.getAndSet(false)) {
                         return objectMapper
                             .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                             .writeValueAsString(event);
                     }
                     return "," +
                         objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(event);
                 } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 return null;
             });

         return Multi.createBy().concatenating().streams(beginDocument, generatedCustomer, Multi.createFrom().items("]}}"));

     } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new CustomerException("Exception occurred during the generation of Customer : " + e);
     }
 }
```